# WSO2 ESB WstxEOFException read adress endpoint

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, wso2

I have an api resource in wso2 like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/akademik" name="GetListStudent" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/students">
    <inSequence>
        <header scope="default">
            <m:complexHeader xmlns:m="http://org.synapse.example">
                <property key="SOAPAction" value="getListStudent"/>
                <property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
            </m:complexHeader>
        </header>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address format="soap11" uri="http://localhost:8080/AkademikSOAP/Service?wsdl"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

and the wsdl : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49439028/Service.xml

when i try to access the api it's shows

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
<S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope>
        <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</faultstring>
    </S:Fault>
</S:Body>
```

but when I try wsdl from wso2 [sample wsdl](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49439028/SimpleStockQuoteService.xml) it's perfectly worked

what happen? 
how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

With an address endpoint, you should remove the ?wsdl at the end of your uri that become : `http://localhost:8080/AkademikSOAP/Service`

Comment: When you "try to access the api", you send it a message and the ContentType is set according to the payload : text/xml for a soap11 message with a xml prolog (version, encoding) and the complete soap envelope / body ?